# Azure function is not allowing to create an class object inside function method

Tags: c#, azure-functions

Created azure Function app and inside the function method unable to call the class objects. Following is my code snippet where I'm  trying create objects for 3 different classes. Azure function is completed with errors when I am doing the same.

```
public static class testSample
{

    [FunctionName("testSample")]
    public static void Run([TimerTrigger("*/5 * * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
    {
        OparetionsDB dbContext = new OparetionsDB();
        try
        {
            MatillionAPIRepository matillionData = new MatillionAPIRepository();
            D365Repository d365Data = new D365Repository();
            log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
            //log.Info(matillionData.saveImportedData().ToString());
            //log.Info(d365Data.getD365JobsResults().ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            dbContext.saveExceptionTime("", ex.GetaAllMessages(), DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please could you provide details of the errors?

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting? Are the classes dependent on configuration/information? We need something more to go on here... Please refer to [mcve].

Comment: [Error] Function completed (Failure, Id=a0c1d447-48bb-42e9-a730-3d5257dddbcf, Duration=266ms) this was the error .

Comment: Nope, that's not the exception. That's the error the Function ends with. What's the `Exception` message you're getting? (Hint: put a breakpoint inside the catch and look at the `ex` variable)

Comment: ifound that issue is with connection string it was working in my local only in azure i had  an issue

Answer (score 0):

From your description, your problem is you didn't set the [AzureWebJobsStorage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azurewebjobsstorage). This is a required storage account connection string in App Settings for all triggers except HTTP trigger.

So in the portal, please go to Application settings and add New application setting. Then update it.

[image]